# init gets killed on syscall

Tags: linux, system-calls, 32-bit, osdev

I'm trying to build an OS on a 32 bit Linux kernel. I made start.S and init.c and executed them, but init keeps getting killed when syscall is made. How can i fix it (start.S and init.c combine to /bin/init)?

start.S:

```
.globl _start
.text
_start:
    call main
```

init.c:

```
int syscall(int nr, void * a0, void * a1, void * a2, void * a3, void * a4, void * a5) {
    int ret;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "mov %0, %%eax\n\t"
        "mov %1, %%ebx\n\t"
        "mov %2, %%ecx\n\t"
        "mov %3, %%edx\n\t"
        "mov %4, %%esi\n\t"
        "mov %5, %%edi\n\t"
        "mov %6, %%ebp\n\t"
        "int $0x80\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %0\n\t"
         : "g="(ret) : "g"(nr), "g"(a0), "g"(a1), "g"(a2), "g"(a3), "g"(a4), "g"(a5) : "%eax", "%ebx", "%ecx", "%edx", "%esi", "%edi");
         return ret;
}
int main(void) {
    syscall(0x4, 1, "Hello", 5, 0, 0, 0);
    while(1) {}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good job solving the issue yourself. You may want to write a well formatted answer if this is a common issue with some of the osdev documentation.